# How do I match ordering of 2 different arrays, that have the same items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matching

I have 2 javascript arrays:

```
const arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'];
const arr2 = ['five', 'six', 'four', 'three', 'one', 'two'];
```

PS- I cant change/control order of 'arr1'

My question is how can I make the order of the items of 'arr2' match that of 'arr1'.

I have been thinking it might look something like:

```
//1. Some kind of function to get index of all items
const items = (item) => item === item; 
const arr3 = arr1.findIndex(items);

//2. Then think I need to get the values of arr2 using ([Array.values()][1])**
const arr2vals = arr2.values();

//3. Then some kind of calculation that matches the values, this is where I really struggle more, but weak at best lol!
arr3.filter(value => arr2vals.includes(value))
```

** Ref: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values)

Comment: You could sort them and then compare them

Comment: you want to check if 2 arrays are identical?

Comment: @Taplar Updated my question, but I can't sort the first arr1, but yep I will have another go by sorting 2nd

Comment: Saying you cannot control order is an inaccurate statement.  `arr1.slice(0).sort()` would sort the first array, without affecting the original.

Comment: @aRvi I want to sort arr2 to match ordering of arr1

Comment: @Taplar, sorry what I mean is, a scenario where arr1 order was fixed, but get what you mean

Comment: So, this is slightly confusing.  Because if you have two different arrays and the second one has the same elements, and you want them to be in the same order, why do you need the second array?  Once you get it sorted to match, it is literally a duplicate of the first array.

Comment: @Taplar - yep I see your point of view and agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array.sort

```
const arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'];
const arr2 = ['five', 'six', 'four', 'three', 'one', 'two'];

/**
Takes in a compare function as parameter where ordering is decided 
based on a more less or equal to 0 return value. 
More than 0 says next should have a lower index than prev
Less Than 0 puts next at a higher index and 0 keeps them at the same index
*/
arr2.sort((prev, next) => {
    return  arr1.indexOf(prev) - arr1.indexOf(next);
})
```

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object which keeps the order values of the items and sort the second array with the delta of the values.

Please have a look to [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and the sorting with numbers.

Maybe you ask, why not using zero as value? This approach allows to use a default value by using this pattern:

```
array2.sort((a, b) => (order[a] || defValue) - (order[b] || defValue));
```

`defValue` can be

- `-Number.MAX_VALUE` a negative large number which sorts all items without an order to top of the array,
- `Number.MAX_VALUE` a positive large number which sorts all items without an order to bottom of the array,
- or any other number for getting a sorting inbetween the wanted order.

```js
const
    array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'],
    array2 = ['five', 'six', 'four', 'three', 'one', 'two'],
    order = Object.fromEntries(array1.map((value, index) => [value, index + 1]));

array2.sort((a, b) => order[a] - order[b]);

console.log(...array2);
```